# Record team meeting using azure bot

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I added compliance policy For recording team meeting using azure bot, but i am not able to record team meeting. Do we need to have an account in third party like: "callcabinet" for recording or we can record it without any third party vendors.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on your ask ?

Comment: i am using this code to join and record ongoing meeting, I am able to join the meeting but not able to record it. I am using following code for join and recording.They are asking for compliance policy and third party "callcabinet" for enabling recording. i just enabled calling policy but should i have to get subscription of "callcabinet" also. Please help me in how to record team meeting using my azure bot. Please help me, this is my humble request.

Comment: var status =RecordingStatus.Recording;

              await graphServiceClient.Communications.Calls[statefulCall.Id]
                    .UpdateRecordingStatus(status)
                    .Request()
                    .PostAsync();

Comment: Could you please refer below doc: https://kb.verba.com/display/docs/Configuring+Microsoft+Teams+Recording

Comment: Is it not possible to record team meeting without any third party vendor.???

Comment: The document you shared is telling to use third party vendor "virent verba".???

Comment: It seems like we have to use third party vendor to enable recording

Comment: Can you suggest any vendor, which can only provide me to enable recording. I dont want any service from them because i am making my own bot app to do those things.

Comment: Please follow this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/teams-recording-policy#compliance-recording-for-teams-certification-programs  But not sure if these are only to enable recording without any service.

Answer (score 0):

We need to create virtual machines in Azure with recording server roles which will be hosting the Verba Microsoft Teams Bot service and the unified call recorder service.  It will record the calls in the same server region of the team's tenant. The servers need to have the public IP address

Need to manage the Azure application gateway, load balancers which can handle the load from different locations. CNAME entry must be created in a public domain.

Content Security Policy (Browser level) also called as CSP headers need to be changed and manages and only CSP certificates are supported

All the firewall rules need to be managed and must be checked with all possibilities.

The following are the steps related to creating the Microsoft teams recording bot.

Step1 : Registering the bot

Step 2: Whitelisting the App

Step3: Creating compliance policy

Step4: Configure Verba App for Microsoft team recording.

For more information check the link below.

https://www.kb.verba.com/display/docs/Configuring+Microsoft+Teams+Recording

Comment: Still looking for help. We don't want any third party. We need to create our own. Please help me with this.

Comment: It seems like we have to use third party vendors.